# Missing Feature{name=auth_api_credentials_begin_sign_in, version=8}

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I use this procedure
https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/create-new-accounts?hl=fr

But i have error in method
oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInRequest)(firebaseCredential)

with error message :
Missing Feature{name=auth_api_credentials_begin_sign_in, version=8}

Thomas

```
    oneTapClient = Identity.getSignInClient(this);
    signInRequest = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
            .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                    .setSupported(true)
                    .setServerClientId(getString(R.string.web_client_id))
                    .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                    .build())
            .build();

    SignInButton signInButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button_google);
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInRequest)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(activity, new OnSuccessListener<BeginSignInResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(BeginSignInResult beginSignInResult) {
                            try {
                                startIntentSenderForResult(beginSignInResult.getPendingIntent().getIntentSender(), REQ_ONE_TAP, null, 0, 0, 0);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                Log.e("Google Login", "Couldn't start One Tap UI : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(activity, new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.d("Google Login Failure", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).